# Can't partition Macintosh HD or increase free space, Error shows 'The target disk is too small for this operation'

Tags: disk-utility, partition

I tried to partition Macintosh HD but it shows an error

> The target disk is too small for this operation, possibly due to partition map limits. : (-69519)

but my disk shows more than 600gb free space

[image: diskutil list]

Comment: What do you want to do? Create a new Container or jhfs partition, by reducing the current container? If yes what's the size and the partition type desired?

Answer (score 1):

Below are three possible answers.

> Note: Shrinking `disk1s2` either will not be possible or will be by to small an about to be worth doing.

- The question does not specify the amount of free space. If for example, the amount of free space desired on the internal HDD was 200 GB on `disk0`, then you would need to subtract this from the space current occupied by `disk0s2`. The result would be `1000.0 GB - 200 GB = 800 GB`. So the command would be as shown below.

  ```
  diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 800G
  ```
- If instead of free space, you are trying to create a new 200 GB partition containing a "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" formatted volume labeled `My Volume`, then the command would be as shown below.

  ```
  diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 800G jhfs+ "My Volume" 0
  ```

  Other formats are available. A table of commonly used formats is given below.

  | Desired Format | String to use in `diskutil` command |
  | --- | --- |
  | Mac OS Extended (Journaled) | jhfs+ |
  | APFS† | jhfs+ |
  | ExFAT | exfat |
  | MS-DOS (FAT) | fat32 |

  † In the case of the APFS format, you will need to enter the following additional command to complete the formatting.

  ```
  diskutil apfs convert "My Volume"
  ```
- Otherwise, if you are trying to add new APFS volume labeled `My Volume` to the existing APFS container, then the command would be as shown below.

  ```
  diskutil apfs addvolume disk2 apfs "My Volume"
  ```